# Вывод по свойству товара

Tags: битрикс

подскажите пожалуйста,
есть раздел с товарами (например, ID 4888), у товаров свойство В наличии (VNALICH) со значениями Да (true) и Нет (false),
вопрос как правильно, сделать условие для вывода:
если в наличии - то товар разрешен к покупке и его можно заказать (сюда я может кнопку вставлю),
если нет - то, товар отсутствует.

торговые предложения не используются. 
в общих чертах так.

с arFilter пробовал, какие то пример, что нагуглил, не заработал ни один.

Comment: А настройки компонента "Каталог" для кого придумали? Там есть опция показывать товары и выбор.

Comment: это нужно через api, я бы не писал, если бы нужно было через стандартные настройки

Comment: Нужно знать каким компонентом выводите, какой вы код писали и он не работает. Приводите эту информацию. Пока вот накидал общий пример в ответ как сделать свой фильтр.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как создать фильтр - этот код должен быть размещен над кодом вызова компонента:

```
global $arNewsFilter;
$arNewsFilter = array(
    "=PROPERTY_CODE" => "VNALICH"
);
```

Вместо `CODE` - прописываете символьный код поля своего свойства. Слово `PROPERTY` обязательно. Важное значение для написания своего фильтра играет тип поля.
Затем в поле компонента который выводит товары подставляете свой фильтр вместо того который там задан.
А конкретно в параметр `FILTER_NAME` передаете свое значение. Пример:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news",
    ...
    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
    ...
?>
```

Comment: @dead4nv в условии для сравнения должно быть 2 знака равенства. И вы уверены, что если товар в наличии, то в свойстве `VNALICH` в значении именно `true`? Вам нужно сравнивать именно с тем значением, которое там лежит. Истиной значение может быть и для пустого значения. `if ($arItem['PROPERTIES']['VNALICH']['VALUE'] == 'Y'
and $arResult["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"] == 9999
) 
{
$availableOnRequest = true;
$arItem['CAN_BUY'] = false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arItem['PROPERTIES']['VNALICH']['VALUE'] = true
and $arResult["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"] = 9999
) 
{
$availableOnRequest = true;
$arItem['CAN_BUY'] = false;
}
```

Comment: по такому пути пошел.

Comment: правда, почему то не отделяет инфблок 9999 от остальных, и 
    $availableOnRequest = true; 
    $arItem['CAN_BUY'] = false; глушат работающие разделы